Encode in Base64
Input: a string in a representation supported by your language
Task: Output the string's representation in base64.
code-golf, so fewest bytes in each language wins!
Here's a example base64 encoder in JavaScript:
    const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
    let output = '';
    let buffer = 0;
    let bitsInBuffer = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        buffer = (buffer << 8) | str.charCodeAt(i);
        bitsInBuffer += 8;

        while (bitsInBuffer >= 6) {
            output += chars[(buffer >> (bitsInBuffer - 6)) & 0x3F];
            bitsInBuffer -= 6;
        }
    }

    if (bitsInBuffer > 0) {
        output += chars[(buffer << (6 - bitsInBuffer)) & 0x3F];
    }

    while (output.length % 4) {
        output += '=';
    }

    return output;

Without usage of any external libraries.

Without built-in functions?

trivially,
Bash, 6 bytes
base64

Attempt This Online!
